# Extracting required information from two tables using Spark and Scala

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have to join two tables and keep col3 as such in table1 and if data is not present in table1 but present in table2 then it can be taken as such.

table 1

```
col1  col2   col3

,,,,  ,,,,   ,,,,
a      p     d
b      q     e
c      r     f
d      s     g
```

table 2

```
col1  col2   col3

,,,,  ,,,,   ,,,,
a      m     s
e      q     l
```

required output

```
col1  col2   col3
,,,,  ,,,,   ,,,,
a      m     d
b      q     e
c      r     f
d      s     g
e      q     l
```

I tried the following code

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SQLContext}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object Tasktr {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Myapp").setMaster("local[2]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    val df1 = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load("/home/magnetto/Desktop/ip.csv")
    val df2= sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load("/home/magnetto/Desktop/del.csv")
    df1.registerTempTable("tab1")
    df2.registerTempTable("tab2")
    val df3=sqlContext.sql("select * from tab1 FULL OUTER JOIN tab2 ON tab1.val1=tab2.val1").show()
```

i got following output

```
val1|val2|val3|val1|val2|val3|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  k1|  l1|   a|null|null|null|
|  k2|  l2|   b|null|null|null|
|  k3|  l3|   c|null|null|null|
|  k4|  l4|   d|  k4|  l4|   e|
|null|null|null|  k5|  l9|   f|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

I have tried full outer join on the two tables but could not get the desirable output.

Comment: Post your code  and the output wanted

Comment: i have used the above code

Answer (score 1):

Given the dataframes as

table1

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|a   |p   |d   |
|b   |q   |e   |
|c   |r   |f   |
|d   |s   |g   |
+----+----+----+
```

and

table2

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|a   |m   |s   |
|e   |q   |l   |
+----+----+----+
```

You can achieve the result you desire by doing the following. Renaming is done to avoid the conflict while applying functions after `join`

```
val tempTable2 = table2.select('col1, 'col2.as("col22"), 'col3.as("col23"))

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
table1.join(tempTable2, Seq("col1"), "outer")
  .withColumn("col2", when('col22.isNotNull, 'col22).otherwise('col2))
  .withColumn("col3", when('col3.isNull, 'col23).otherwise('col3))
  .drop("col22", "col23")
```

which will give you result as

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|e   |q   |l   |
|d   |s   |g   |
|c   |r   |f   |
|b   |q   |e   |
|a   |m   |d   |
+----+----+----+
```

Comment: is there any way we can do without renaming the columns...something like df1.col1,df1.col2 and df2.col1,df2.col2